# Python | I'm getting an error when seeing if a list has an element or not

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey so the other day I was messing around with some code and it gave me this error.

> if clearargs[1] == "history":
>   \n IndexError: list index out of range

```
elif startswith(ui, "clear") or startswith(ui, "clr"):
    clearargs = ui.split()
    if len(clearargs) < 1:
        refs.clearscr("Windows", os)
    else:
        if clearargs[1] == "history":
            history = []
            os.remove(hfilepath)
        elif clearargs[1] == "exthistory":
            extendedhistory = []
            os.remove(ehfilepath)
```

btw most functions are custom defined

Comment: (It might help to revisit [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) about the "origin" of sequences.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list index starts from zero.

So, if the length of the list is exactly one, than `clearargs[0]` is the right access to the first value in the list.

When asking to get the value from `clearargs[1]`, you assume that the length of the list is at least 2.

Answer (score 0):

else block will be executed only when the`len(clearargs < 1)` so the only valid index  is `clearargs[0]`.You are making a logical error.